# Why does my simple linear model learn a threshold function f(x) = (x > 0) on the dataset g(X) but perform poorly on X?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

Why does the *validation loss* increase while *train loss* decreases when training data is x and validation data is gen(x)?

I made a `classifier(SimpleModel)`.
when I train a classifier with `input=torch.randn(100,1)` and `label=(1 if input>0, else 0)`, the classifier is trained well with validation accuracy~1.

[image]

However, when I train the clssifier with `input=gen(torch.randn(100,1))` and `label=(1 if input>0, else 0)`, wherein `gen()` is a model I made. the classifier is not trained well. The *train loss* decreases, but validation accuracy doesn't decrease. The final validation accuracy was ~0.5

[image]

What's the problem?

The code is:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch import optim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class SimpleModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleModel, self).__init__()
        self.linear1=nn.Linear(1,1)
        self.sigmoid=nn.Sigmoid()
    def forward(self,x):
        x=self.linear1(x)
        x=self.sigmoid(x)
        return x

class Gen(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Gen, self).__init__()
        self.linear1=nn.Linear(1,2)
        self.relu1=nn.ReLU()
        self.linear2=nn.Linear(2,1)
        
        
    def forward(self,x):
        x=self.linear1(x)
        x=self.relu1(x)
        x=self.linear2(x)      
        return x
model=SimpleModel()
gen=Gen()
criterion = nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001)
loss_history=[]
val_loss_history=[]
acc_history=[]
val_acc_history=[]



for step in range(10000):
        
    z=torch.randn(100,1)
    
    x=gen(z)
    label=(x>0).float().reshape(-1,1)
    out=model(x)
    loss=criterion(out,label)
    
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    acc=(out.round()==label).float().mean()
    
    val_x=torch.randn(100,1)
    val_label=(val_x>0).float().reshape(-1,1)    
    val_out=model(val_x)
    val_loss=criterion(val_out,val_label)
    val_acc=(val_out.round()==val_label).float().mean()
    
    print(loss.item(), acc.item(), val_loss.item(), val_acc.item())
    
    loss_history.append(loss.item())
    val_loss_history.append(val_loss.item())
    acc_history.append(acc.item())
    val_acc_history.append(val_acc.item())

plt.figure()
plt.plot(loss_history, label="train loss")
plt.plot(val_loss_history, label="validation loss")
plt.legend()
```

Comment: There is no programming problem here, there are no guarantees about validation performance of any model. That a model works on data X does not mean it will work on data Y.

Answer (score 2):

The random variable `gen(X)` is distributed differently from `X`. It is not unsurprising that a model `f : X -> {0, 1}` trained on a different distribution will perform poorly if that model does not generalize well out-of-distribution, or if it is not given the right training examples.

The "ideal" function `f` for labeling `x` is evidently `f(x) = (x > 0)`. However, in order to train `f_theta`, we must give enough examples of `x` that is both above and below the threshold of `0`. So I imagine one of the following must be occurring:

1. `gen(X)` does not map to enough examples of one of the labels, e.g. `f(gen(X)) = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...}`.
2. The "probabilistic" support of `X` is *vastly* different from `gen(X)`, e.g. `P[X ∈ [-3, 3]] = 0.95`, but `P[gen(X) ∈ [-1000, 1000]] = 0.95`.
3. The model `f_theta` is not able to model a decision boundary, e.g. the model `f_theta(x) = (theta * sin(x) > 0)` cannot match the ideal `f` under the support of `x ∈ R`.

Given that `f_theta(x) = σ(theta_1 * x + theta_2)`, I think (1) or (2) are much more likely to occur than (3). For instance, if

```
X = {0.3, 1.1, -2.1, 0.7, 0.2, -0.1, ...}
```

then I doubt that any of the following datasets are good for training `f_theta`:

- `gen(X) = {200, 500, 100, 700, 500, 300, ...}` demonstrates (1)
- `gen(X) = {-200, 500, -100, 700, -500, 300, ...}` demonstrates (2) since a possible model `f(x) = σ(1000 * (x + 10))` does fine on `gen(X)`, but terribly on `X`.

Comment: I suggest that you do not answer obviously off-topic questions, the question itself is not about a programming problem.

Comment: Thank you. After reading your answer, I used min_max_normalize(gen(x)) as training data and min_max_normalize(x) as validation data. now, it works very well.